# Quick Launch is empty with Design Manager Snippet in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-branding

I'm trying to create a custom master page in SharePoint 2013. I've following options 1. Through HTML 2. Minimal Master page. Following either of above doesn't provide Quick Launch. I tried to put snippet from Master page but it's empty. Please let me know if you've faced similar scenario.

Regards,
Vikrant